# Vue.js 2 - Sharing XHR Data between Views WITHOUT using Vuex?

Tags: vuejs2, vue-router

I'm teaching myself Vue.js 2.  My task is to pull a list of posts from the Hacker News API.  Upon clicking a list post, a new view is to display some of the data from that specific post.

**I'm having a very tough time understanding how to get the REST API data populated in the 2nd view upon routing to the 2nd view, from the 1st view.**

(I'm using vue-router and vue-resource(?), and not Vuex (it's such a small application).)

Below are the Item.vue and List.vue.  From the List.vue, I'm trying to route to the Item.vue by clicking on a list item.  For example, click on a list item called "Guy Has Tough Time with Vue", then open a 2nd view to display a title, score, URL, and comments of the post "Guy Has Tough Time with Vue".

List.vue (creates list, XHR request)

```
<template>
<div class="list-container">
<h1>List Vue</h1>
<ul class="item-list" v-for="(item, index) in this.items">
  <li>
    <router-link class="list-item" :to="/views">
      {{index + 1}}. {{item.title}}
      <div class="points">
        Points: {{item.points}}
      </div>
    </router-link>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
 name: 'List',
 props:[]
 data(){
  return {
    items: []
  }
 },
 mounted: function(){
   console.log("created");
  this.fetchList();
 },
 methods: {
   fetchList(){
  this.$http.get('http://hn.algolia.com/api/v1/search?query=javascript&hitsPerPage=25').then((response) => {
     this.items = response.data.hits;
   })
  }
 }
}
```

Item.vue (Receives item-specific data from List.vue)

```
<template>
 <video id="bgvid" playsinline autoplay loop>
   <source src="./src/assets/rad.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <div class="item-container">
<h1>Item Vue</h1>
<div class="post-title"></div>
<div class="post-score"></div>
<div class="post-url"></div>
<ul class="post-comments">
  <li class="sngl-comment">

  </li>
</ul>

</div>
</video>
</template>
<script>
export default {
 name: 'Item',
 data(){
   return {
   item: {}
 }
},
mounted: function(){
  console.log("created");
},
methods: {

}
 }
</script>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the first view isn't a direct descendant of the second view so you can't pass data to it through props. I actually wouldn't be using `vuex` for this, instead I would pass an `id` through the route for the specific list item and fetch that individual item by the id, as an example:

```
const View1 = {
  template: `<div>
    <ul>
      <li v-for="item in list"><router-link :to="'view2/'+item.id">{{item.name}}</router-link></li>
    </ul>
  </div>`,
  data() {
    return {
      list: [{
        id: 1,
        name: 'foo'
      }, {
        id: 2,
        name: 'bar'
      }, {
        id: 3,
        name: 'baz'
      }]
    }
  }
}

const View2 = {
  template: `<div>Fetch item {{id}} <br /><router-link to="/">back</router-link></div>`,
  created(){
     console.log('Fetch data for item '+ this.id);
  },
  computed:{
    id(){
      return this.$route.params.id
    }
  }
}

const routes = [{
  path: '/',
  component: View1
}, {
  path: '/view2/:id',
  component: View2
}]

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes // short for `routes: routes`
})

var app = new Vue({
  router
}).$mount('#app')
```

Here, I've set the route on `View2` to be: `view2/:id` (see: [Dynamic route matching](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/dynamic-matching.html)), now in the View2 component I can access that id via `this.$route.params.id` (which I've put in a computed). Once I've got that `id` I can simply make an ajax request for the data for the specific item.

And here's the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/craig_h_411/3hwr6mcd/

**Using Vuex**

If you are unable to retrieve a record by the specific id for some reason and you don't want to duplicate the call, you will need to share state between non-descendant components and that's where Vuex comes in.

There is a misconception with vuex that it's complicated, but if you only want to share state between a couple of components, it's really quite simple (and it's less than 10kb in size) so there really isn't much use trying to avoid it, all you need to add to your project is:

**store.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex)

const store = {
  state:{
    item: {}
  },
  mutations:{
    setItem(state, value){
      state.item = value;
    }
  }
}

export default new Vuex.Store(store)
```

Then in your app.js (or wherever you have you main Vue instance) you would do something like:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import store from './store'

import App from './components/App.vue'

new Vue({
  store, // this will be available in components via this.$store
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

You will also have to make a few changes, such as committing the state before pushing to the route, adding a computed to get the state from the store and removing the id from the route as it's no longer needed.

I've updated the JSFiddle to show you how that would work: https://jsfiddle.net/craig_h_411/bvswc0kb/

Comment: Craig, thanks.  My trouble is that when I route to "View2", I'm only passing that "id" valule.  I need the data of the entire item: ({id: blah, points: 893, url: newyorktimes.com/article/blah}).   How do I get an entire data hit (object) into "view2"?  Does that make sense?  

I need to populate fields in view2, with data from item in "view1".

Comment: If you can't retrieve an individual record by the id, then you will need to extract the state, which means you should use vuex. I've updated my answer to show you how to do that (don't worry, it's pretty simple)

Comment: Craig, thank you.  You've helped a lot.  Why remove the router-link for an anchor tag?

Comment: That's because I'm calling a method on click. You can't register a `click` event on `router-link`, so we wouldn't be able to call the method that sets the item in the store. In order to get that to work you need to set the item then call `router.push` programatically, so I've used an anchor instead.

Comment: Ah, I see. Craig, you've been a great help. Thank you.